# NextAuth shows me errors when embedding with Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

If I try to integrate NextAuth into my application with Typescript, I get 2 errors. Once at NextAuth and at NextAuthOptions.

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = ({
 providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: `${process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}`,
      clientSecret: `${process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}`, 
    })
  ]
})

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

> Module '"next-auth"' has no exported member 'NextAuthOptions'.ts(2305)

> This expression is not callable.
> Type 'typeof import("next-auth")' has no call signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following types/**/*.ts in tsconfig.json:

```
{ 
  .
  .
  .
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "types/**/*.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  .
  .
  .
}
```

then add the following in next-auth.d.ts

```
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth";

    // this process is know as module augmentation
    declare module "next-auth" {
      interface Session {
        user: {
          id: string;
        } & DefaultSession["user"];
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was having an issue with my `next-auth.d.ts`. Check out the link: https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#module-augmentation

Answer (score 0):

```
    import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
    import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

    export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
     providers: [
      GoogleProvider({
      clientId: String(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID),
      clientSecret: String(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET),
      }),
     ],
    };

  export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```